# getting transform node string & list? Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

I've appended a list and it turns out like this:

```
[[u'polyToCurve1', u'polyEdgeToCurve1'], [u'polyToCurve2', u'polyEdgeToCurve2'],....etc
```

I need it to select a list of all the 'polyToCurve#' transform nodes and nothing else but I'm not sure how to get there... pretty new to this so this might be an easy answer but IDK...

```
selection = cmds.ls(selection=True, flatten = 1)
curveList = []

for i in selection:
    cmds.select(i, r=True)
    curveList.append(cmds.polyToCurve(form= 0, degree= 3))
    print curveList
```

I just need a list of plain polyToCurve#'s that I can then use cmds.select on again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selection = cmds.ls(selection=True, flatten = 1)
curveList = []

for i in selection:
    cmds.select(i, r=True)
    curveList.append(cmds.polyToCurve(form= 0, degree= 3)[0])
    print curveList
```

you just have to select the first index of the output list of the function

Comment: That worked thank you! I didn't realize I could pull each out with the index #

Comment: it might be more obvious in two lines : curve = cmds.polyToCurve(form= 0, degree= 3) and then curveList.append(curve[0])

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is with a list comprehension:

```
curveList = [curve for (curve, edgeCurve) in curveList]
```

The middle part here splits the two-element lists into two variables, then the first part pickes the first of those elements. The list comprehension as a whole makes a single list consisting of just those.

Comment: do I put this under curveList.append? I just tried that and I got this: # ValueError: too many values to unpack #